# ado.net Linq query with join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ado.net

Here is my edmx diagram.

[image]

I am trying to use

`UserEntity.users.ToList<user>();`

This provides me with a complex object of `User`s that contain `user_groups`, but I can't seem to find the `Group` information. My understanding is that EF is supposed to abstract out the join table and provide me with direct access to the `Group` information.  Please note I am coming from cakephp and hoping for a similar style result!

Edit:  Model Code

```
 public static class UserModel
    {
        static UserEntities dataContext = new UserEntities();

        public static void CreateUser(user _newUser)
        {
            dataContext.users.AddObject(_newUser);
            dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public static List<user> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return dataContext.users.ToList<user>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Julien...please share your Model code. You need to define the properties and linkages correctly in the Object's .cs files.  I'm not clear as to what is it you exactly want.  You want to see group and user_groups?

Comment: Habib's answer at first glance seems like what I need. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one to many relationship between `users` and `user_group`, so you may select a single `user_group` from `users` and against that you will get group.

```
var result = users.user_group.FirstOrDefault().group;
```

The Navigation property `user_group` in `users` will have a collection of `user_group` objects, you may select `First` or anything based on your requirement and then select `group` from there.

Comment: I do not have access to `group` from `user_group` like this

Comment: @Julien, I  missed the one to many relationship between users to user_groups, check the edited answer now